# Navigating away when a Flutter FutureProvider resolves it's future

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection, state

I'm basically looking for a way to either start loading data, or navigate to the Login Screen.

The FutureProvider gets it's value from SharedPreferences.  The default homescreen is just a logo with a spinner.

If the userID resolves to null, the app should Navigate to the Login Screen, otherwise it should call a method that will start loading data and then on completion navigate to the main page.

Can this be achieved with FutureProvider?

I add it to the page build to ensure the page widget will subscribe to the Provider:

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    userInfo = Provider.of<UserInfo>(context);
    print('Building with $userInfo'); 
    return PageWithLoadingIndicator();
....
```

I added it to didChangeDependencies to react to the change:

```dart
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    print('Deps changed: $userInfo');
    super.didChangeDependencies();
//    userInfo = Provider.of<UserInfo>(context); // Already building, can't do this.
//    print('And now: $userInfo');
    if (userInfo == null) return;
    if (userInfo.userId != null) {
      startUp(); // Run when user is logged in
    } else {
      tryLogin(); // Navigate to Login 
    }
  }
```

And since I can't use Provider.of in initState I added a PostFrameCallback

```dart
  void postFrame(BuildContext context) {
    print('PostFrame...');
    userInfo = Provider.of<UserInfo>(context);
  }
```

Main is very simple - it just sets up the MultiProvider with a single FutureProvider for now.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  Future<UserInfo> getUserInfo() async {
    String token = await UserPrefs.token;
    return UserInfo.fromToken(
      token,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'App One',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
      ),
      home: MultiProvider(
        providers: [FutureProvider<UserInfo>(builder: (_) => getUserInfo())],
        child: LoadingScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that as it is now I can see from the print statements that "didChangeDependencies" gets called twice, but the value of userInfo is always null, even though build() eventually gets an instance of UserInfo as evident by the print statement in the build() method.

I'm guessing I can add some logic into the build method but that screams against my sensibilities as the wrong place to do it... perhaps it isn't as bad as I think?

Comment: Have you tried to call   userInfo = Provider.of<UserInfo>(context); in the didChangeDependencies?

Comment: Yes, you cannot do that.  It results in an error because Build is already underway.

Comment: I think the problem is that Provider only wants to build Widgets, not control the flow of the app.  So for now on this page in initState I added a call to an async function that will await the sharedPreferences and then either navigate away or start the data loading process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided that this is conceptually the wrong approach.

In my case I wanted to use a FutureProvider to take the results from an Async function which create a "Config" object using SharedPreferences.  The FutureProvider would then allow the rest of the app to access the user's config settings obtained from sharepreferences.

This still feels to me like a valid approach. But there are problems with this from an app flow perspective.

Mainly that the values from the shared preferences includes the logged in user session token and username.

The app starts by showing a Loading screen with a Circular Progress bar.  The app then reads the shared preferences and connects online to check that the session is valid.  If there is no session, or if it is not valid, the app navigates to the Login "wizzard" which asks username, then on the next page for the password and then on the next page for 2-factor login.  After that it navigates to the landing page.  If the loading page found a valid session, the login wizzard is skipped.

The thing is that the two things - app state and app flow are tangenially different.  The app flow can result in changes being store in the app state, but the app state should not affect the app flow, at least not in this way, conceptually.

In practical terms I don't think calling Navigator.push() from a FutureProvider's build function is valid, even if context is available.  I could be wrong about this, but I felt the flowing approach is more Flutteronic.

```dart
 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   _loadSharedPrefs().then((_) {
     if(this.session.isValid()) _navToLandingPage();
     else _navToLoginStepOne();
     }
   }
```

I'm open to better suggestions / guidance